# Charts from Modern UI Toolkit are not rendered correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create a Windows Store app with some simple charts, however i found that there is no chart controls for these apps. Searching the net i found there is some expensive third party charts that i cannot afford. In the end i found a free Toolkit from: http://modernuitoolkit.codeplex.com

This worked fine for me, but just for 5 values. if i try to graph 30 values it gets all messed up as illustrated in the picture below:
[image]

After studying the example provided i modified it by adding 30 values to the chart.

```
        List<NameValueItem> items = new List<NameValueItem>();       

        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test1", Value = arrayOfValue[0] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test2", Value = arrayOfValue[1] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test3", Value = arrayOfValue[2] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test4", Value = arrayOfValue[3] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test5", Value = arrayOfValue[4] });

        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test1", Value = arrayOfValue[5] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test2", Value = arrayOfValue[6] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test3", Value = arrayOfValue[7] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test4", Value = arrayOfValue[8] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test5", Value = arrayOfValue[9] });

        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test1", Value = arrayOfValue[10] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test2", Value = arrayOfValue[11] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test3", Value = arrayOfValue[12] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test4", Value = arrayOfValue[13] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test5", Value = arrayOfValue[14] });

        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test1", Value =arrayOfValue[15] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test2", Value = arrayOfValue[16] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test3", Value = arrayOfValue[17] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test4", Value = .arrayOfValue[18] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test5", Value = arrayOfValue[19] });

        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test1", Value = arrayOfValue[20] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test2", Value = arrayOfValue[21] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test3", Value = arrayOfValue[22] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test4", Value = arrayOfValue[23] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test5", Value = arrayOfValue[24] });

        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test1", Value = arrayOfValue[25] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test2", Value = arrayOfValue[26] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test3", Value = arrayOfValue[27] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test4", Value = arrayOfValue[28] });
        items.Add(new NameValueItem() { Name = "Test5", Value = arrayOfValue[29] });


        ((ColumnSeries)Chart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items;
        ((BarSeries)BarChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items;
        ((LineSeries)LineChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items;
        ((ColumnSeries)MixedChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items;
        ((LineSeries)MixedChart.Series[1]).ItemsSource = items;
        ((AreaSeries)AreaChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items;
        ((BubbleSeries)BubbleChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items;
        ((ScatterSeries)ScatteredChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items;
```

NameValueItem is defined as:

```
  public class NameValueItem
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    private double _value;

    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
    public NameValueItem()
    {
    }
}
```

The MainPage Xaml looks like this:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App17"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Series="using:ModernUI.Toolkit.Data.Charting.Charts.Series"
xmlns:Axis="using:ModernUI.Toolkit.Data.Charting.Charts.Axis" 
xmlns:Charting="using:ModernUI.Toolkit.Data.Charting"

xmlns:DataPoints="using:ModernUI.Toolkit.Data.Charting.Charts.DataPoints"

xmlns:Chart="using:ModernUI.Toolkit.Data.Charting.Charts.Chart"
xmlns:series="using:ModernUI.Toolkit.Data.Charting.Charts.Series"

x:Class="App17.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

```
  <Canvas x:Name="can" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="381,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
  <Chart:Chart x:Name="Chart"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Column Chart" Margin="-2,153,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" Height="190">
     <Chart:Chart.Series>
        <series:ColumnSeries
                        Title="Population"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
                        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
     </Chart:Chart.Series>
  </Chart:Chart>
  <Chart:Chart x:Name="BarChart"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Bar Chart" Margin="316,153,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" Height="190">
     <series:BarSeries
            Title="Population"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
  </Chart:Chart>

  <Chart:Chart x:Name="LineChart"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Line Chart" Margin="-2,363,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" Height="190">
     <series:LineSeries
            Title="Population"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
  </Chart:Chart>
  <Chart:Chart x:Name="MixedChart"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Mixed Chart" Margin="316,363,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" Height="190">
     <series:ColumnSeries
            Title="Population"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
     <series:LineSeries
            Title="Population"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
  </Chart:Chart>
  <Chart:Chart x:Name="AreaChart"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Area Chart" Margin="634,363,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" Height="190">
     <series:AreaSeries
            Title="Population"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
  </Chart:Chart>
  <Chart:Chart x:Name="BubbleChart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Bubble Chart" Margin="634,153,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" Height="190">
     <series:BubbleSeries
            Title="Population"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
  </Chart:Chart>
  <Chart:Chart x:Name="ScatteredChart"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Scattered Chart" Margin="952,153,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" Height="190">
     <series:ScatterSeries
            Title="Population"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
  </Chart:Chart>
```

the data in the arrayOfValue looks like this: 
-3.7
 -6
2.9
-0.2
1.2
2.5
-1
-1.2
-0
-5.3
-7.1
-4.8
-1.2
0.8
-1
-1.5
-1.4
-5.2
-3.4
-6.6

Comment: And you expect us to help you by looking in our glass ball? Post some code and give us some information, what you have already tried to solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry! i added my code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your code doesn't compile - arrayOfValue is too short.
2. You're only getting 5 values because your X axis only has 5 different values (Test1-5) - if you fix that - the charts work fine
3. A newer version of the same charts has been integrated into WinRT XAML Toolkit [here](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c5#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/ChartTestPage.xaml). You can grab the source code from CodePlex or a package from NuGet [here](http://nuget.org/packages/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization).
4. Looking for the original project I stumbled upon another charting toolkit that might work for you - http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks!! it helped changing the Names of Test(1-5) :) I really liked your two last suggestions also, but im not sure yet how to implement them in my code.I will keep trying.

Comment: Hi, regarding the WinRT XAML Toolkit. I have added the DLLs as in the Sample however i am getting the following error:                                             Error 1 Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed